# How to apply polymorphic function to a concrete type?

Tags: haskell

Below is a distilled version of a problem I encountered while learning Haskell:

```
data A = A
data B = B

data Test = TestA A
          | TestB B

test :: (a -> a) -> (Test -> Test)
test op t =
  case t of
    TestA a -> TestA $ op a
    TestB b -> TestB $ op b

testA = test id (TestA A)
testB = test id (TestB B)
```

Trying to compile this gives the following error:

> Couldn't match expected type ‘B’ with actual type ‘a’
>
> ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
>   the type signature for test :: (a -> a) -> Test -> Test

What's going on? I thought that when I pass in a polymorphic function, I should be able to apply it to values of different concrete types.

Comment: @AlexisKing: for this function, `Rank2Types` is enough. Currently, GHC implements `Rank2Types` via `RankNTypes` but theoretically there is a possibility to do more type inference if you only use rank-2 types; getting into the habit of using the right language extension should be more future-proof in case GHC gets type inference of rank-2 types at some point.

Comment: @Cactus The official GHC documentation considers `Rank2Types` to be nothing short of deprecated, so I see no reason to believe there is any intention to make the sort of change you suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem here is how Haskell infers quantification from free variables in type signatures. Given the following type signature...

```
test :: (a -> a) -> (Test -> Test)
```

...the type variable `a` is unbound. Haskell automatically converts unbound type variables into universal quantification constraints, so the above type is actually interpreted like this:

```
test :: forall a. (a -> a) -> (Test -> Test)
```

Now the error you are getting might make a little bit more sense—the type variable `a` can only unify with *one* type per invocation of `test`, which is decided by the caller. Therefore, the `(a -> a)` function could be `String -> String` or `Int -> Int` or any other type, but it can never be a function that works on both `A` and `B`.

Obviously, though, you had a different intent when you wrote that type signature. You wanted the `(a -> a)` function to be a type signature like the one for `id`: a function that truly works for *any* value, not some particular function for some particular choice of `a`. To specify this, you must make the `forall` explicit so that the compiler knows precisely how that type variable should be quantified:

```
test :: (forall a. a -> a) -> (Test -> Test)
```

However, the above type is actually not valid in standard Haskell. It *is* supported by GHC, though, by using the `Rank2Types` or `RankNTypes` extension, which permits “higher rank” polymorphism like the type signature above.

Comment: Incidentally, the only possible total function of type `forall a. a -> a` is `id` - to do anything meaningful with `a` you'll need a constraint, for example `forall a. C a => a -> a`.