# How to apply a polymorphic function to both sides of an Either?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, rank-n-types

I tried this:

```
type TestT = Either Int Float

testM :: (a -> a) -> TestT -> TestT
testM f (Left x) = Left (f x)
testM f (Right x) = Right (f x)
```

but it doesn't work, is there any way to do this? I did some looking around and everything similar was really complicated and limited.

Error message, as requesed:

```
Main.hs:101:28: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘Int’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          testM :: forall a. (a -> a) -> TestT -> TestT
        at Main.hs:100:1-35
    • In the first argument of ‘f’, namely ‘x’
      In the first argument of ‘Left’, namely ‘(f x)’
      In the expression: Left (f x)
    • Relevant bindings include
        f :: a -> a (bound at Main.hs:101:7)
        testM :: (a -> a) -> TestT -> TestT (bound at Main.hs:101:1)
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Can you give some context? Just seeing code that doesn't solve your problem gives only hints about what your problem is.

Comment: One possibility would be to enable `RankNTypes` and use something like `testM :: (forall a. (Num a, Ord a) => a -> a) -> TestT -> TestT`, but that's *probably* a lot fancier than you really need and I have no idea if it would even solve your problem.

Comment: You can't with a single `f`, since that `f` has type `a -> a`, but left and right here have `Int` and `Float`. Except with some extra extensions, as dfeuer specifies, this is not possible.

Comment: One way around this, without involving higher rank types, would be to pass in *two* functions, one of type `Int -> Int` and one of type `Float -> Float`. (And then `testM` would be the same as [bimap](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors-5/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html#v:bimap).) But since your title refers to a polymorphic function, it seems you might indeed want a Rank 2 type as @dfeuer suggests. It's far from clear what your actual intention is here, and whether it's a purely theoretical question or motivated by a specific problem.

Comment: @binarycat - It would be great if you could include the full error message you got from the compiler (as that helps search engines) and add the tags for "polymorphism" and "rank-n-types" to your question. Thanks !

Comment: `a -> a` isn't a placeholder for an arbitrary monomorphic function like `Int -> Int` or `Float -> Float`; it's the type of function that can accept a value of any type. `id` is the only function with type `a -> a`. There's no way to statically type `testM` so that it only accepts a function that works with whatever *runtime* value `Left x` or `Right x` is passed.

Comment: @chepner yes, that would be the cause if the problem was that I couldn't *use* the function in the example with something like `(+3)`, but it wouldn't even let me *define* it. shouldn't I still be able to call `testM` with `id`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do that in the base language. As mentioned in the comments, you might need to enable a couple of extensions, such as RankNTypes.

As all involved types are numeric ones, it is tempting to use an increment function, such as (+1) as the polymorphic function.

Let's try under `ghci`:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.6.5: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
 λ> 
 λ> type TestT = Either Int Float 
 λ> 
 λ> :set +m
 λ> 
 λ> :set -XRankNTypes
 λ> :set -XScopedTypeVariables
 λ> 
 λ> {-
|λ> let { testM :: (forall a. Num a => a -> a) -> TestT -> TestT ;
|λ>       testM fn (Left x) = Left (fn x) ;
|λ>       testM fn (Right x) = Right (fn x) }
|λ> -}
 λ> 
 λ> :type testM
testM :: (forall a. Num a => a -> a) -> TestT -> TestT
 λ> 
 λ> testM (+3) (Left 42)
Left 45
 λ> 
 λ> testM (+3) (Right 3.14159)
Right 6.14159
 λ>
```

**Note 1:** If you omit the language extensions, it breaks, with a message hinting to RankNTypes.

**Note 2:** If you use `forall a. Num a => (a -> a)` instead of `(forall a. Num a => a -> a)`, it also breaks.

**Note 3:** Some prior art here: [SO-q38298119](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38298119/how-to-apply-polymorphic-function-to-a-concrete-type) with a useful comment from Alexis King.

Comment: This still lets you pass a function of, say, type `Integer -> Integer` as the first argument, which can't be applied to either part of a `TestT` value.

Comment: @chepner This is wrong on many levels. 1: no, no it doesn't, you get a type error, as you should. 2: still? the orignal function didn't, because it *wouldn't compile*. 3: you made it really hard for this comment to follow the rule of threes.

Comment: Bah, I ran afoul (I think) of the monomorphism restriction. You're right.

Comment: Both `RankNTypes` and `ScopedTypeVariables` imply `ExplicitForAll`, so you don't have to enable the last explicitly.

Comment: @dfeuer - You're right ; fixed, thanks ! - But frankly that's one aspect of Haskell I do not feel comfortable with.  Why do they need to have so many features under "extension" status ? It feels a bit like having to type `#pragma lambda_expressions` in C++ or `!GCC$ AllowMultidimensionalArrays` in Fortran :-)  Hopefully a new version of the Haskell standard will fix that some day.

Comment: @jpmarinier, it's hard to have a meaningful standardization process when there's only one really viable implementation. Hopefully some day another will arise. Purescript is a Haskell, but it takes things in quite a different direction from GHC, so I don't know if a standardization process with just those would go anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is with Bifunctor:

```
Prelude> :m +Data.Bifunctor
Prelude Data.Bifunctor> bimap show show (Left 3)
Left "3"
Prelude Data.Bifunctor> bimap show show (Right 'x')
Right "'x'"
Prelude Data.Bifunctor>
```